# How to convert the Int column into a string in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-athena

Since I am a beginner of Pyspark can anyone help in doing conversion of an Integer Column into a String?

Here is my code in Aws Athena and I need to convert it into pyspark dataframe.

```
       case when A.[HHs Reach] = 0 or A.[HHs Reach] is null then '0'
        when A.[HHs Reach] = 1000000000 then '*'
        else cast(A.[HHs Reach] as varchar) end as [HHs Reach]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming df is your dataframe, something like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "HHs Reach",
    F.when(F.col("HHs Reach").isNull(), '0')
    .when(F.col("HHs Reach") == 1000000000, '*')
    .otherwise(F.col("HHs Reach").cast("string"))
)
```

Comment: hi @Steven, According to the code I enclosed this will work. But if there are many CASE statements, will this work?

Comment: @sowmiya I am not sure to understand what you mean. Can you be more explicit ? maybe post some example. Each `when` is is the equivalent of `F.when`. and `else` is `otherwise`. it is as simple, works with as many case when that you want.